What is the fastest way to talk in English and transcribe in a different language on iOS in any application?
From time to time on my iPhone I use speech recognition in English and then translate the transcription into a different language, and finally use that translation in some input field in some application. For example I might use Telegram or Line, and need to send a message in Korean or German, but I want to use speech recognition in English as this is the language I commonly speak. What's the fastest way to do so?
Currently I use the Google Translate app to transcribe and translate. However this requires me to copy paste the resulting translation into the target application. Is there a more efficient way to do so?


Open the chat app you want to send a German message in

Use the dictation feature of iOS to dictate the English version

Select the dictated text, then select “Translate” from the pop-up menu


Let Apple’s translate app translate the text, then select “Replace with translation”


Review translation and send



